# WebSphere deployment error - WASX7109E: Insufficient data for install task "MapResRefToEJB

Tags: java, spring, ejb, websphere, udeploy

I have upgraded Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE to Spring 4.3.16.RELEASE

While deploying the changes to the WAS 8.5.5.12 I'm seeing the below issue.

I do see that JNDI reference exists in WAS and it doesn't complain to deploy 
for version with older spring (3.1.0)  version build

```
**0181106-100154 (I) __main__ execute 
'com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7109E: Insufficient data for 
install task "MapResRefToEJB**


    ADMA0007E: A validation error occurred in task Mapping resource 
 references 
    to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not 
    specified for resource reference url/LogoffServiceurl in module abc with
```

EJB name .

I have below entry in AppContext file..

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="logoffURL" jndi-name="url/LogoffServiceurl "/>

    pom.xml


  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

     <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    Web.xml

        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
                 xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
                 version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">

    Also have in ear module pom

       <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It looks like you are are missing `url/LogoffServiceurl` resource. If it is already configured on your WebSphere, check if it is in the correct scope - maybe it is scoped to different server/cluster. Also try to install application manually via console and see if same error appears and if you have option to map that resource correctly during the installation.

Comment: Thanks @Gas for your response. Yes, the URL url/LogoffServiceurl has been configured and works properly if I deploy the older ear file built with Spring 3.1. Also tried the manual deploy and could map to appropriate URL..

Comment: How do you install that application?

Comment: I install it using - IBM tool uDeploy..

Comment: Update --- I can make the application deployable by reverting the web.xml servlet version from 3.1 to 2.4.

Comment: In that case this is uDeploy issue not WebSphere, especially that you can deploy same through the console.